# Fixing error img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Tags: pytorch

I tried to create Custom dataset but when show the some images it had the error. Here is my Dataset class and tranforms:

```
transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224,224)])

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, label,  transform=None):
        self.path = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg'))
        self.transform = transform
        self.label = label

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = io.imread(self.path[index])
        img = torch.tensor(img)
        labels = torch.tensor(int(self.label))
        if self.transform:
          img = self.transform(img)
        return (img,labels)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.path)
```

And here error line:

```
images, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transforms.Resize` requires `PIL.Image` instance as `input` while your `img` is a `torch.Tensor`.

This will solve your issue (see comments in source code):

```
import torchvision
from PIL import Image

# In your transform you should cast PIL Image to tensor
# When no transforms on PIL Image are needed anymore
transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224, 224), transforms.ToTensor()])


class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, label, transform=None):
        self.path = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.jpg"))
        self.transform = transform
        self.label = label

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(self.path[index])
        labels = torch.tensor(int(self.label))
        if self.transform is not None:
            # Now you have PIL.Image instance for transforms
            img = self.transform(img)
        return (img, labels)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.path)
```

Comment: @TrọngVăn On StackOverflow we don't say "thank you" for an answer. If you wish to thank the author you can upvote the answer. Glad I could help.